# Android CameraX - dynamically attach ImageAnalysis.Analyzer

Tags: android, android-camerax

I have implemented my own subclass of `ImageAnalysis.Analyzer` and it works as expected. Now I want to "attach/detach" this analyzer to the `ImageAnalysis` class dynamically (based on some user actions). From the `ImageAnalysis` API it looks like it is possible, there is [setAnalyzer](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis#setAnalyzer(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis.Analyzer)) method and also [clearAnalyzer](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis#clearAnalyzer()) method. However, this works correctly only on the first `setAnalyzer` call. If I call then `clearAnalyzer` and `setAnalyzer` again, `analyze` method is not called.

In the documentation of `clearAnalyzer` method is

```
Removes a previously set analyzer.

This will stop data from streaming to the ImageAnalysis.
```

so it looks like its working maybe correctly as expected? That it will stop data streaming to `ImageAnalysis`. But is it possible to clear/set analyzer the way I want? I dont want to add some `enabled` boolean flags to my analyzer, there is threading issues, image queue issues and the solution with set/clear would be the cleanest I think.

Comment: This seems like a potential bug, the second set analyzer doesn't seem to receive any frames from the camera. It would be great if you filed a bug for this issue. In the meantime, if you don't want to use a boolean flag, instead of dynamically adding/removing the Analyzer, you can dynamically add/remove the imageAnalysis use case itself.

Comment: Ok, reported https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151605317. Thanks :)

Comment: @Billda, after some hours find your question for the same problem. Have you found another way to solve the problem?

Comment: @Jon no, i've ended up with Boolean flag in my analyzer, but you can try the solution that Husayn suggested

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this bug is fixed now, but if anyone still stumbles upon such behavior, make sure you didn't forget to call `ImageProxy.close()` somewhere.